# What is the difference between agones and spatial OS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, multiplayer, game-development, agones

recenty google announce an open source project called Agones partnership with ubisoft..
it is an open source, dedicated multiplayer game server hosting on google cloud..
source : https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/03/introducing-Agones-open-source-multiplayer-dedicated-game-server-hosting-built-on-Kubernetes.html

but last year, google also introduce their partner's (https://improbable.io/) project called Spatial OS..
which claim to be the next generation of multiplayer gaming..

my question what is the difference?
in term of performance on real time multiplayer, mitigating cheating and also which one has the lowest server maintenance (to be maintained by developer)

or are they actually different things and can work together to create a better online multiplayer game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agones and Spatial OS are different things and used for different use cases.

1) Agones is a "dedicated server hosting solution".
So you upload a dedicated server (executable) and it gets managed (distributed, started, stopped ...) across servers/nodes.

Similar solutions are:

- Gamelift by Amazon (SaaS): https://aws.amazon.com/gamelift
- Multiplay by Unity (SaaS): https://multiplay.com/

Agones allows to host this yourself. You would typically use this for FPS, 3rdPS like games - Fortnite, PUBG etc.
This does not include the Game Engine and multiplayer technology: E.g. Unreal Networking or Photon Bolt.

2) Spatial OS is a Service + Platform to build seamless/MMO type of games or simulations.

Like https://www.worldsadrift.com/ by Bossa.

Comment: Agones founder here - this answer is spot on! 